# Non-EU citizen wants to join his EU citizen wife

Tags: visa, eu, resident-permit, austria, marriage

I'm a Slovak citizen living in Austria (since 14 yrs).

I've recently married a Moroccan citizen.

How can he apply to join me under EU laws of EU spouse visa?

Comment: I assume you have been working in Austria? (It could make a difference)

Comment: im living and working in austria yes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no personal experience with that but your husband must in any case obtain an [“Aufenthaltskarte für Angehörige aus Drittstaaten”](https://www.help.gv.at//Portal.Node/hlpd/public/content/12/Seite.120830.html) (see also the website of the [Austrian embassy in Rabat](http://www.bmeia.gv.at/fr/ambassade/rabat/conseils-pratiques/aller-en-autriche/permis-de-residence.html)). It's distinct from the regular “Familienzusammenführung” (“regroupement familial” on the embassy's website). I can't find the right form online but it's important to insist on that as it should be easier to obtain.

Note that it's not uncommon for consulates to make difficulties or be unaware of the details of the rules. If the consulate is uncooperative, you might want to hire a lawyer or seek help from [SOLVIT](http://ec.europa.eu/solvit/index_en.htm).

Comment: oh realy ! but you mean a tourist visa for austria ? iv been told that he must apply for a reunification visa from morocco ! but it may take longer and lot of requinquents !

Comment: @dobru10 That's called [“Familienzusammenführung”](http://www.migration.gv.at/de/formen-der-zuwanderung/dauerhafte-zuwanderung-rot-weiss-rot-karte/familienzusammenfuehrung.html) and it's indeed more complex but that's only a requirement if you are yourself a citizen from a “third country” (i.e. not EU) or possibly an Austrian citizen. The rules are different for EU citizens and their family. That's the theory at least.

Comment: oh great ! so can you tell me how long his first visa can take ? is it tourist ?
thank you for your help its very helpful

Comment: @dobru10 It seems I was wrong, your husband can apply for this “Aufenthaltskarte für Angehörige aus Drittstaaten” directly at the embassy in Rabat. In any case, he does not need to satisfy the requirements for the regular “Familienzusammenführung”. I will edit my answer to add some details.

Comment: thank you ! im waiting ! i need all infromations to understand all my rights !